# C# + PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

Хочу в C# через powershell узнать сумму MD5 файла одного, прописал такой небольшой скрипт

```
string script = @"$dataLocal=Get-FileHash -Path C:\Script1.ps1 -algorithm MD5";
```

В powershell чистом все работает хорошо, а тут постоянно пишет не может найти диск С. Я уже все варианты кавычек-двойных кавычек-слэши...все перепробовал

Попробовал через Set-Location предварительно сделать, но опять же, в powershell все работает, а в C# опять пишет не может найти диск С

Подскажите как правильно указывать путь в С#, если это обычная строка string, которую я потом запускаю powershell.addScript(script).Invoke();

Уверен, что как-то надо по-другому путь указывать к файлу...кто сталкивался - подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Вы уверенны, что у Вас там `C`, а не `С`?

Comment: )))) проверил на всякий случай, та же ошибка, не может найти диск С, потому что его не существует. На всякий случай попробовал с диском D, также пишет не может найти

Comment: Вам это обязательно через powershell делать?

Comment: @tym32167 мне надо сравнить суммы md5 двух файлов, один на моем компьютере, другой на удаленном. Не думал что будут такие проблемы с указанием директории. Ладно я еще смогу посчитать md5 средствами C#. но удаленный файл по-любому надо будет считать через powershell мне...а вообще да, надо все сделать через powershell но в коде C#

Comment: Что выводит `Get-PSDrive` если вызывать из C#? Как создаётся `Runspace` в котором выполняется код? Если использовать `-Path FileSystem::C:\Script1.ps1`, то работает или нет?

Comment: @PetSerAl Вариант `-Path FileSystem::C:\Script1.ps1`  сработал, все теперь нормально с директорией. Спасибо большое!!! Можно как ответ написать!

Answer (score 0):

А зачем тебе в C# идти через PowerShell ?

Это дотнет-ный код для PowerShell:

```
[System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create('MD5').ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('S:\dtim-beacon.gif'))
```

Без проблем адаптируешь для c#